# Simple Android app fails without starting

Tags: android

Hello there people of stack overflow, I have just started developing with android and have run into a bit of a problem. I am trying to run a very simple app that has a single button, which when clicked updates the text to the current time. However, the app does not even start up. I am following a book. "Beginning Android 2", and am just learning about XML layouts. The same app worked without an XML layout, so it may be something to do with my xml.

Anyways, I'm running it on a droid 2, if that helps.

Heres the codes.

```
package apt.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Date;

public class FirstApp extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        updateTime();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        updateTime();
    }

    private void updateTime() {
        btn.setText(new Date().toString());
    }
}
```

And the XML file

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the future, when you have issues and would like help, please include the output of `adb logcat *:D` when you experience the issue. With this information, it will reduce the amount of guessing that has to go into providing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose the button inside a layout (linear, relative, etc):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the book didn't mention that. I'll accept asap

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are incorrect. The only line missing in that xml is the first one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Of course you will need some kind of ViewGroup to make any meaningful UI, but setContentView can take **any** View as parameter

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your root layout must be a ViewGroup. Change the layout to something like this for example:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```